# Can we talk to remote Websphere MQSeries purely with non-Websphere MQSeries software

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel, ibm-mq

We're trying to talk to a WebSphere MQSeries installation on the remote machine of an external organization. We don't have IBM WebSphere MQSeries ourselves.

I've been looking at open source alternatives like Apache ServiceMix/Camel/ActiveMQ and also Oracle Database Gateway for WebSphere MQ (since we are using Oracle) but each solution requires both the client install provided as SupportPac MQC7 which is a free download plus the IBM jar com.ibm.mqjms.jar

Is there a way to exchange messages with WebSphere MQSeries in production purely with non-Websphere MQSeries software?

Thanks

Comment: "I have Oracle and need to talk to WMQ, how do I do it?" seems a valid question to me.  The answer (which may be valuable for others) is to download the *latest* client which comes with extended transactional support and all the required jar files.  HTTP://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC75  Putting the word "license" in the question should not be cause to shut it down.

Comment: the key issue though is the need for the proprietary IBM jar.

Comment: Everything you need is in the MQC75 SupportPac.  Including the jar files.

Comment: actually, I downloaded the zip and it didn't contain the required jar file

Comment: You need to install the WMQ Client and then look into the installed software to find the jar file. Put the java folder in the installation on your classpath to use IBM WebSphere MQ.

Comment: Petter is correct.  The client distribution from IBM is an installer.  Run it and it will unpack the jars for you.  Be sure to run it on the server where you plan to run the code because in addition to the jars, it installs lots of tools and diagnostics such as native WMQ trace.  And if you ever want support form IBM the installer package is what they support, not just a grab of the jars. (Specifically so that they can have you run the diags if you open a PMR.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest WMQ client contains the jar files and all of the native WMQ diagnostics and tools.  Also, note that the latest distributions include Extended Transactional Client without charge and include that functionality in the regular jar files. (In other words, no longer a separate ETClient.jar file.)  The latest download is at [SupportPac MQC75](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC75).

Note that the download is an installer file and does not contain the jar files as a separate folder.  The intention from IBM is for you to run the installer on each and every server where you will run WMQ client.  Although this is a bit heavyweight versus just grabbing the jar files, the installer contains many diagnostic tools such as `dspmqver`, the native WMQ trace, the `mqrc` program to tell you the meaning of return codes, the code samples, etc.  With the full bundle installed, it is a lot easier for IBM to provide support.  Considering that they provide support for a free component, requiring the full install seems reasonable to me.

There are no other methods for communicating with a WebSphere MQ QMgr other than using the official WMQ client or another WMQ QMgr.  Even though WMQ talks JMS, that's an API spec and not a protocol spec.  It is necessary to use the Java JMS classes provided by the vendor of your chosen transport which, in this case, means using IBM's JMS classes.  The same is true for running .Net code with WMQ.  Gotta use IBM's classes.

The one exception is that WebSphere App Server Messaging Engines can interoperate with WMQ.  These are pure JMS messaging engines written in Java but they understand the WMQ formats and protocols and appear to WMQ as another QMgr.  So if you have WAS you can talk to WMQ without a WMQ client or another QMgr.

Comment: With your last paragraph option, if you just had WebSphere App Server with the Messaging Engines you might send JMS ok and look like an MQ QMgr but how would you receive JMS from a queue. I set up ActiveMq as a JMS provider in WAS but can I make ActiveMQ queues look like MQ queues to an exterior connected MQ Series QMgr?

Comment: using for example Camel?

Answer (score 2):

It's worth also knowing that the WebSphere MQ Resource Adapter can be downloaded directly from FixCentral. The installer for this is very much like the WebSphere Liberty profile installer, that is a jar file you run, accept the license, and the WMQ RA appears on disk. That can then be installed to your application server of choice.

Although the documentation at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21633761 is centered around the Liberty profile, this is the same RA as with the standard forms of MQ install therefore can be used in any JavaEE server support.

The support statement for the WebSphere MQ RA is at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27023129. Essentially if you can get the RA installed into a JavaEE compliant server, can run the IVT you can raise a PMR.

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere MQ has a Telemetry feature which allows an MQ server to be configured as an MQTT server.  There are a number of open source MQTT clients (e.g. www.eclipse.org/paho) which can be used to exchange messages with WebSphere MQSeries using the pub/sub model