# Does WebSphere Application Server's MQ link facilitate connecting to third party JMS providers

Tags: websphere, activemq-classic, ibm-mq

An earlier question on interoperating with MQ Series and a pure open-source solution was answered partly with:

```
  "The one exception is that WebSphere App Server Messaging Engines can interoperate with WMQ. These are pure JMS messaging engines written in Java but they understand the WMQ formats and protocols and appear to WMQ as another QMgr. So if you have WAS you can talk to WMQ without a WMQ client or another QMgr."

 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236860/can-we-talk-to-remote-websphere-mqseries-purely-with-non-websphere-mqseries-soft)
```

The documentation I've read through says that
WebSphere Application Server using WebSphere MQ link can operate with a service integration messaging engine or queue-sharing group.

So as I understand it, if you have WAS and WebSphere MQ link you could connect an WebSphere esb to an exterior MQ Series QMgr and look like a QMgr to that exterior MQ Series QMgr.

Without a WebSphere esb though can WAS act like a MQ QMgr and somehow manage third-party JMS messaging providers like ActiveMQ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are mixing up capabilities.

- WAS can absolutely appear to WMQ as another QMgr when using the WMQ Link.  The QMgr appears to WAS in this configuration as another Service Integration Bus.
- Service Integration Bus or SIB is the WAS abstraction for a JMS transport provider.  It isn't the same thing as IBM's Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) product.  Both talk to WMQ but WAS is in no way dependent on the ESB product to do so.
- Either WMQ or any other pure JMS transport can be configured in WAS as a Foreign JMS Provider.  The administrator points WAS to the JMS classes provided by the transport provider.  These can include Active MQ.

There is no concept of WAS seeing WMQ but managing some other transport such as Active MQ.  WAS can use normal JMS API calls to interact with Active MQ or any other transport provider.  It can also make use of whatever administration API is provided by that transport provider using that provider's administration API.  Since both WAS and MQ are IBM products, the integration is a bit tighter between them which is why you can use WMQ natively whereas other JMS transports must be configured as foreign JMS providers.